# How to eliminate a dummy dimension of ndarray?

Tags: python, numpy

How can I eliminate a dummy dimension in python numpy ndarray?
For example, suppose that A.shape = (0, 1325, 3),
then how can eliminate '0' dimension so that A.shape = (1325,3).

Both 'np.sqeeze(A)' or 'A.reshape(A.shape[1:])' don't work.

Comment: try this:    np.squeeze(A, axis=0).shape

Comment: If a dimension is zero it is an empty array no? Did you mean `(1, 1325,3)` ?

Comment: try this y= a[0,:, :]

Comment: @BlueTomato This will never work.

Comment: How did you get there? That is, how did you get to this `(0, 1325, 3)` shape?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't eliminate that 0 dimension.  A dimension of length 0 is not a "dummy" dimension.  It really means length 0.  Since the total number of elements in the array (which you can check with `a.size`) is the product of the `shape` attribute, an array with shape (0, 1325, 3) contains 0 elements, while an array with shape (1325, 3) contains 3975 elements.  If there was a way to eliminate the 0 dimension, where would that data come from?

If your array is supposed to contain data, then you probably need to look at how that array was created in the first place.

Comment: 0 element was created during matrix/vector appending in the for loop (for example, appending a vector (1325, ) to (1325, ) in axis=1). Anyway, I managed to eliminate '0' element in the dimension. Thanks for your comment.